# OSError [Errno 22] invalid argument when use open() in Python

Tags: python

```
def choose_option(self):
        if self.option_picker.currentRow() == 0:
            description = open(":/description_files/program_description.txt","r")
            self.information_shower.setText(description.read())
        elif self.option_picker.currentRow() == 1:
            requirements = open(":/description_files/requirements_for_client_data.txt", "r")
            self.information_shower.setText(requirements.read())
        elif self.option_picker.currentRow() == 2:
            menus = open(":/description_files/menus.txt", "r")
            self.information_shower.setText(menus.read())
```

I am using resource files and something is going wrong when i am using it as argument in open function, but when i am using it for loading of pictures and icons everything is fine.

Comment: For someone else that gets a similar error, you may have invalid characters (for example `:` or `?`) in the filename.

Comment: Another scenario (that I just ran into) is if you are trying to write to a file inside a DropBox folder and you just had that file open very recently, you can run into this same error caused by DropBox has detected the changes and is attempting to process your new file.

Comment: Ditto, this can also be the case for a OneDrive file.

Answer (score 52):

That is not a valid file path. You must either use a full path

```
open(r"C:\description_files\program_description.txt","r")
```

Or a relative path

```
open("program_description.txt","r")
```

Comment: What does the initial r in open(r"C:\file-path\file.txt", "r") signify?

Comment: @Calydon The leading r denotes a python raw string. It treats \ as a literal character. No need to escape it.

Answer (score 14):

Add 'r' in starting of path:

```
path = r"D:\Folder\file.txt"
```

That works for me.

Comment: what is the use of "r" in prefix, what does that means?

Comment: @RoshanYadav 'r' refers to 'raw string'.  Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742691/python-path-and-raw-strings

Answer (score 12):

I also ran into this fault when I used `open(file_path)`. My reason for this fault was that my `file_path` had a special character like `"?"` or `"<"`.

Comment: I had the same problem. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

I received the same error when trying to print an absolutely enormous dictionary. When I attempted to print just the keys of the dictionary, all was well!

Answer (score 6):

**For me this issue was caused by trying to write a `datetime` to file.**

Note: **this doesn't work:**
`myFile = open(str(datetime.now()),"a")`

The datetime.now() object contains the colon ''':''' character

To fix this, use a filename which avoid restricted special characters. Note this resource on detecting and replacing invalid characters:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593932/9053474

For completeness, replace unwanted characters with the following:

`import re`

`re.sub(r'[^\w_. -]', '_', filename)`

Note these are Windows restricted characters and invalid characters differ by platform.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was using an invalid string prefix.

Wrong:

```
path = f"D:\Folder\file.txt"
```

Right:

```
path = r"D:\Folder\file.txt"
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the error was due to lack of permissions to the folder path. I entered and saved the credentials and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem
It happens because files can't contain special characters like ":", "?", ">" and etc.
You should replace these files by using replace() function:

```
filename = filename.replace("special character to replace", "-")
```

Answer (score 2):

you should add one more "/" in the last "/" of path, that is:
`open('C:\Python34\book.csv')` to `open('C:\Python34\\book.csv')`. For example:

```
import csv
with open('C:\Python34\\book.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: There's a set of problems with this answer:
1) `open('C:\Python34\book.csv')` to `open('C:\Python34\book.csv')` -> There is no difference between the two lines. Did you mean `open('C:\Python34\book.csv')` to `open('C:\\Python34\\book.csv')`?

2) Both the code in the example and in the first line is wrong, as you're not escaping backslashes (or, in the case of your example, all of them.)
`'C:\Python34\\book.csv'` should be `'C:\\Python34\\book.csv'` or `r'C:\Python34\book.csv'`

Comment: If you click Edit you'll see that @hiep-tran did type double slashes, but SO rendered these as single slashes. I fixed the formatting with backticks around the example commands.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows-Pycharm: If File Location|Path contains any string like `\t` then need to escape that with additional `\` like `\\t`

Answer (score 2):

Just replace with "/" for file path :

```
   open("description_files/program_description.txt","r")
```

Comment: I am facing same issues like this. But , i replace with "/", it is work well.

Answer (score 1):

just use single quotation marks only and use 'r' raw string upfront and a single '/'

for eg

```
f = open(r'C:/Desktop/file.txt','r')
print(f.read())
```

Comment: I downvote this, since this answer is **very** misleading. Single and double quotes make no difference. Raw strings are not needed for strings without escape sequences (and only backslash introduces those). The only good part here is "use forward slash, even if on windows", but it's lost in remaining gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

I had special characters like '*' in my strings, for example for one location I had a file `Varzea*`, then when I tried to save ('Varzea*.csv') with f-string Windows complained. I just "sanitized" the string and all got back to normal.

**The best way in my case was to let the strings with just letters**, without special characters!

Answer (score 0):

```
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(unicode(docs_dir, 'utf-8')):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.startswith('.'):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,the problem exists beacause I have not set permission for drive "C:\" and when I change my path to other drive like "F:\" my problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel ('C:/Users/yourlogin/new folder/file.xlsx')
print (df)
```

Comment: It would be better if you could add more instructions to the answer, rather than just pasting the code.

Comment: If you didn't get it, mostly it means use / instead of \.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because old server instance was running and using log file, hence new instance was not able to write to log file. Post deleting log file this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy the path by right clicking the file---> properties-->security, it shows the error. The working method for this is to copy path and filename separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue while working with pandas and trying to open a big csv file:

```py
wrong_df = pd.read_csv("D:\Python Projects\ML\titanic.csv")
right_df = pd.read_csv("D:\Python Projects\ML\\titanic.csv")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using special characters("?", "!", ...) and **not** using raw strings

The "\" character is used to define special symbols within a string("\n" -> new line, "\uXXXX" -> special unicode character, ...)
If you have another symbol after "\", it wont work because python doesnt know what character are you trying to insert. To avoid this, use the "r" prefix for raw strings("\" characters gets interpreted as any other): **r**"path\to\your\file.extension"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I have resolved it by creating a function that converts backslashes to forward slashes. Probably, this may not be the best way but it fixed my issue.

```
bs = r"\""
fs = "\\"    
def bs_to_fs(folder_path):
    folder_path_with_forw_Slash = ""
    for i in folder_path:
        if i == bs:
            folder_path_with_forw_Slash = folder_path_with_forw_Slash+'/'
        else:
            folder_path_with_forw_Slash = folder_path_with_forw_Slash+i
    folder_path_with_forw_Slash = folder_path_with_forw_Slash + fs[:1] 
    return(folder_path_with_forw_Slash)

Folder_path = r"E:\Random_Files\Project1"
open_file_name = "Some_File_Name.txt"

FILE_TO_OPEN = bs_to_fs(Folder_path) + op_file_name

with  open(FILE_TO_OPEN,'w') as file1:
```

Then Continue with rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

### Date and time in filename

I was trying to create a file with **datetime** inside, effectively a .txt named  i.e - 2023-09-19 12:13:01.txt to create a reports file to store problems/results. As others mentioned before the issue is the special signs in the path. Its not a problem on my mac os but I got this error on win10.

### Solution:

```
current_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
```

Formatted filename would look like this 2023-09-19 12-13-01.txt. You can edit the formatting to whatever works best for you and doesn't error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was related to lack of permissions between users in my Windows system. I solve this by executing the IDE as administrator.
Then, I granted permissions to all users and the problem went away.