# OSError unable to create file - invalid argument

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, h5py

I am using Python and Keras on top of Tensorflow to train my neural networks.
When I switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to Windows 10, my model could not be saved anymore when I run the following:

```
filepath = "checkpoint-"+str(f)+model_type+"-"+optimizer_name+"-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.3f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
```

and later on:

```
model.fit(X, y,
      batch_size=128,
      epochs=1,
      shuffle=False,
      callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

I get this Error:

> OSError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name = 'checkpoint-<_io.textiowrapper name='data/swing-projects100-raw/many-chunks/log-gamma-f3.txt' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>2l128-adam-0.001-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.3f}.h5', errno = 22, error message = 'invalid argument', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)

I have Keras 2.0.8 and h5py 2.7.0 installed via conda.

I tried

```
filepath = "checkpoint-"+str(f)+model_type+"-"+optimizer_name+"-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.3f}.hdf5"

with open(filepath, "w") as f:
  f.write("Test.")
```

and got a similar error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "checkpoint-<_io.TextIOWrapper name='data/swing-projects100-raw/many-chunks/log-gamma-f3.txt' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>2L128-Adam-0.001-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.3f}.hdf5"

Comment: i'd suggest trying to save any simple text file with that filepath: f=open(filepath,'w')

Comment: @maz Please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584124/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-use-open-in-python suggests that `filepath` is an invalid filename. If you'd like help determining how to make `filepath` into a valid filename, please add the value of `filepath` that is resulting in the error to the question.

Comment: @SethDifley You can see the value of `filepath` in my question before the first and the second error message. My path is a relative one and I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @AIpeter don't you want to be calling `.format` on that string to put some values in? Braces and colons etc... are valid characters for common linux file systems, so you'll literally getting a file containing "{epoch:02d}" in its name - on Windows - those are not valid characters for a filename..

Comment: @JonClements This wasn't the reason for my error. You can do it this way in Keras. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I removed `str(f)` from the filepath, it worked.
`f` is an Integer and I don't know why it caused the error, but removing it from the string solved my problem.

Let me know if you know exactly why.

Comment: simple, f is not an integer, but a textiowrapper.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Did you mean `str(f)` is a textiowrapper? Because of the `str()` or why should `f=0` be a textiowrapper?

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem when using tensorflow on a distant machine.

the reason of my maybe 'have no permission to modify the file'.

I solve this problem by use the save path like "../model.h5"———the folder where  you have permission.

may this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this code:

```
agent.save("./saved_models/weights_episode_{}.h5".format(e))
```

I solved it by manually creating the folder `saved_models`

`e` being an integer did not cause any problems in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to my using Vscode. When I switched to PyCharm, everything work well.