# Python OSErrror errno22 when creating a file

Tags: python, exception

I get errno 22 with this code:

```
import datetime
now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
filename = "log_{}".format(now)
logFile = open(filename, "w+")
```

Comment: probably related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584124/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-use-open-in-python#25584140

Comment: Windows does not allow `:` in file names

Comment: but the file is in the same folder as the .py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix if you are okay with : being replaced by .:

```
import datetime
now = str(datetime.datetime.now())
filename = "log_{}".format(now).replace(':', '.')
filename
# 'log_2018-09-13 11.39.42.216000'
logFile = open(filename, "w+")
```

It is an issue with the filename containing ":" characters.

Comment: thanks! now it works!

Comment: I the past I've just used `;` it looks about the same, the problem with replacing `:` with `.` is when you go to open the file and delimit the timestamp you can't separate the `.` for microseconds as easily.