# Open files using For-loop (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry I'm new to Python 3 and I already kept looking for an answer here in SO but I can't find the specific answer to my question rather I may not asking the right question.

I have a file named test5.txt where I have written the file names of the files that I want to open/read using Python namely, (test2.txt, test3.txt and test4.txt) these txt documents have random words on it.

Here is my code:

```
with open("test5.txt") as x:
    my_file = x.readlines()

for each_record in my_file:
    with open(each_record) as y:
        read_files = y.read()
        print(read_files)
```

But sadly I'm getting error: `"OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'test2.txt\n'"`

Comment: Do you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584124/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-use-open-in-python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `each_record` contains a newline `\n` character. You can try to strip the filename string before open it as a file.

```
with open("test5.txt") as x:
    my_file = x.readlines()

for each_record in my_file:
    with open(each_record.strip()) as y:
        read_files = y.read()
        print(read_files)
```

Comment: It worked! thank you man digitake! I have been working for 4 hours to figure this out :) .strip() worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest to use `rstrip` rather than `strip` - better to be safe and explicit.

```
for each_record in my_file:
    with open(each_record.rstrip()) as y:
        read_files = y.read()
        print(read_files)
```

But this should also work and is maybe more beautiful, using the `str.splitlines` method - see this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines).

```
 with open("test5.txt") as x:
    list_of_files = x.read().splitlines()
```