# How to open xltx and xltx files using pandas in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xls

Openpyxl would do the job but I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it in pandas or maybe converting a Openpyxl workbook into pandas dataframe? Thank you guys.

edit: 
I found the doc for Openpyxl and tried to do the following 
…

```
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
data = ws.values
col = next(data)[1:]    #error occurred here
```

…

The issue for this script is that xltx file consists of several merged cells.
Error message: 'MergedCell' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 0):

There's a method for that.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xltx')
```

df will be your dataframe. Read all the options [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: That's my first try,and  for some reason it didn't work for me. OSError no. 22 invalid argument.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584124/oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-use-open-in-python

Comment: Most welcome, if the answer is acceptable could you please accept it? Thanks.