# Most efficient way to strip forbidden characters in file name from Unicode string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I have a string which contain some data I parse from the web, and make a file named after this data.

```
string = urllib.urlopen("http://example.com").read()
f = open(path + "/" + string + ".txt")
f.write("abcdefg")
f.close()
```

The problem is that it **may** include one of this characters: `\ / * ? : " < > |`.
I'm using Windows, and it is forbidden to use those characters in a filename.
Also, `string` is in Unicode formar which makes most of the solutions useless.

So, my question is: what is the most efficient / pythonic way to strip those characters? 
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** the filename is in Unicode format **not** str!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033424/how-to-remove-bad-path-characters-in-python

Comment: @NPE Sorry! I googled before but find nothing. Anyway, maybe there are better solutions so I'll keep it up

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is to use `unicode.translate`,

see [unicode.translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692199/string-translate-with-unicode-data-in-python).

```
In [31]: _unistr = u'sdfjkh,/.,we/.,132?.?.23490/,/' # any random string.

In [48]: remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in '\/*?:"<>|')

In [49]: _unistr.translate(remove_punctuation_map)Out[49]: 

u'sdfjkh,.,we.,132..23490,'
```

To remove all puctuation.

```
In [46]: remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

In [47]: _unistr.translate(remove_punctuation_map)
Out[47]: u'sdfjkhwe13223490'
```

Comment: It's probably the most efficient solution out there. Thanks!

Comment: @ohad987 Please mark correct if you find this correct and helping.

Comment: There's a problem- I forgot to mention the I'm using Unicode, which makes this solution useless for me. But, it really great and could help others that use `str` instead.

Comment: @ohad987 Then use `str()` builtin to change unicode to string.

Comment: This string cotain may contain hebrew/arabic/etc chracters, and using `str()` will throw an exeption.

Comment: @ohad987 I think i solved your problem of unicode. check updated solution.

Answer (score 17):

we dont know how your data look like:

But you can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
your_string = re.sub(r'[\\/*?:"<>|]',"","your_string")
```

Comment: The backslash (`\ `) should be escaped. (`'[\\\\/*?:"<>|]'` or `r'[\\/*?:"<>|]'`). Otherwise backslashes will not be removed.

Comment: yes it is, thanks for notifying me

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using unicode, and this solution does'nt work with Unicode strings. Thanks anyway!